# In R Shiny, how to sum specified columns of a dataframe and output the results into a table?

Tags: r, shiny, sum, rendering

Here's an easy one to help make up for some of my other posts. I think it's easy but then again I didn't find solutions that work for me in my searches.

When running the below MWE code, how do I generate a simple table output that shows the sums of the 2 noted columns ('Nbr' and 'MOB')? The below gives me "Error in sum: invalid 'type' (character) of argument".

I'd like a table output (not a value embedded in a text string) because in the full App I'll be adding other sums to the output, building up a larger table.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)

beta <- matrix(c(19,19,19,'2014-07','2014-08','2014-09',1,2,3), 
               nrow = 3, 
               ncol = 3, 
               dimnames = list(NULL,c("Nbr","Month","MOB")))
beta <- data.frame(beta)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("summary")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$summary <- renderTable(c(sum(beta$Nbr,sum(beta$MOB))))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (`Error in sum(beta$MOB) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`) is telling you that you can't perform the function `sum` on a character vector. So you first have to convert to numeric, and then the error goes away.

```
beta <- matrix(c(19,19,19,'2014-07','2014-08','2014-09',1,2,3), 
               nrow = 3, 
               ncol = 3, 
               dimnames = list(NULL,c("Nbr","Month","MOB")))
beta <- data.frame(beta)
```

Add this here:

```
beta[c("Nbr","MOB")]<-sapply(beta[c("Nbr","MOB")],as.numeric)
```

Comment: Since I keyed Nbr and MOB in to the matrix as numbers, I assumed they were numeric. Should have tested for it. Now I know how to do this for the future. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I am not sure why they aren't read in as numbers. It is possible that the matrix is entirely being converted to character because some of the values are characters. I usually start directly with `data.frame(Nbr=c(19,19,19), Month = c('2014-07','2014-08','2014-09'), MOB = c(1,2,3))` and that should have them start as numeric.